# Question on how my civilization can deflect a comet on a decaying elliptical bringing it into a collision course with the earth

Tags: science-based, physics, space

My novel requires that a comet, in an eighty-year elliptical orbit around the earth, changes trajectory due to a friction-like mechanism, resulting in orbital decay that will impact the earth within the length of one orbit, i.e., about sixty years? Is this possible? This is how I envision the scene.

[image: Question 1]

Comment: How do you mean "a friction like mechanism"? Could you give us some details of that.

Comment: A spherical orbit would be 32 million km away, so an extreme elliptical orbit would extend so far away from the Earth it would be affected by the other planets, and even more so by the Moon, and so it wouldn't maintain a stable orbit about the Earth. That's only *one* reason that there *are no comets* that orbit the Earth.